# Is there any way to delete a button after I press it

Tags: python, ursina

Is there any way that I can delete the b_render var when the b_logic function is activated? I have been trying different solutions for about an hour and nothing works. is there anything I overlooked?

```
from ursina import *

def b_logic():
    print("button pressed")

b_render = Button(scale = (.4,.1),color='red',text="start",on_click=b_logic)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if you overlooked anything if you don't tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `destroy(b_render)` will remove the entity completely. If you plan to reuse the button later, I recommend setting `.enabled` to `False` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I stuck at this when I was making a snake game.

```
from ursina import *

def b_logic():
    destroy(b_render) # if you do not want to use it later.
    # or
    # b_render.enabled = False

b_render = Button(scale = (.4,.1),color='red',text="start",on_click=b_logic)
```

Comment: Hope your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy the button with the destroy() function:

```py
def b_logic():
    print("button pressed")
    destroy(b_render)
```